# How to make all GridViews behave the same?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I am facing myself with the following situation:

I have several controls, each containing one DevExpress GridView. What I would like is to have all these GridViews behave the same (for example, pressing the tab key while while inside the gridView should change the focus to another control - this is just an example -).

How can I achieve this without extending the GridView or without extending the control which contains the GridView?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you averse to extending the Gridview? How many grids to you have in your solution? Why can you not copy the same properties for all gridviews?

Comment: `class MyGridView : Gridview`

Comment: @ViSu The number is huge, this is why I was looking for an alternative solution

Comment: @SriramSakthivel without extending the GridView as mentioned in the description

Comment: @mirelvlad That's what we're asking **why**? any reason? There is no magic bullet which gives you what you're trying to achieve. T4 templates can provide generating code for you if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The reason is the huge number of gridViews in the project. Indeed, I was looking for a magic bullet. Anyway, thx for the T4 template idea, I will give it a try.

Comment: Honestly extending is the option when you have number of gridviews in your project, other options like duplicating code is not a ideal solution. That's why inheritance exist for *reusability*. BTW I have extended the devexpress `Gridview` and using it still. So My opinion is go for extending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I came up with the following solution:

I created an extension method on the `GridControl` of the `GridView`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Switches the focus to the next when control on tab key pressed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gridControl">GridView's grid control</param>
    public static void ApplyTabStopBehavior(this GridControl gridControl)
    {
        gridControl.ProcessGridKey += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var gridView = gridControl.FocusedView as GridView;
            if (gridView != null && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            {
                ProcessTabKey(gridView, e);
            }
        };
    }
```

In my case, this method listened for any tab key pressed and performed focus switching.

Hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar thoughts when I realized all of my GVs are acting the same way and I lose a lot of time customizing every new instance. But making a custom descendant is by far the best option (I have cca 200 GVs in my application).

Making a good descendant saves you a lot of time and you can change your existing GVs to the new one with a simple search&replace.

Before extending, be sure to read the article on [DevExpress Support page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A859) about creating design time ready GVs.